# Deformation method of convergence in distribution with respect to the exponential distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, exponential-function, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

## Question

Suppose the following holds
$$
n(\theta - X_{(n)}) \xrightarrow{L} E(0, \theta).
$$
How can this be transformed as follows?
$$
\frac{n}{\theta}(\theta - X_{(n)}) \xrightarrow{L} E(0, 1).
$$

## What I know

$E(0, \theta)$ denotes the exponential distribution with density $\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$ when $x > 0$.

from $n(\theta - X_{(n)}) \xrightarrow{L} E(0, \theta)$, it can be transformed as follows.
$$
n(\theta - X_{(n)}) \xrightarrow{L} 1 - e^{-x/\theta}\\
\therefore \frac{n}{\theta}(\theta - X_{(n)}) \xrightarrow{L} \frac{1}{\theta}\left(1 - e^{-x/\theta} \right),
$$

$$
CDF: \frac{1}{\theta}\left(1 - e^{-x/\theta} \right) \implies PDF: \frac{1}{\theta^2}e^{-x/\theta}.\ ??
$$

Comment: $n(\theta - X_{(n)}) \xrightarrow{L} 1 - e^{-x/\theta}$ is not an equation or even the limit of an equation: the left hand side is a random variable while the right hand side is a cumulative distribution function.  So you cannot divide both sides by $\theta$.  Instead you have to use a change of variables (a rescaling in this case) which has a different effect on the two sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of convergence in law, we have

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf P[n(\theta - X_n)\leq x] = 1 - \exp(-x/\theta).
$$

Now consider $\frac{n}{\theta}(\theta - X_n)$, then

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf P\left[\frac{n}{\theta}(\theta - X_n) \leq x\right] &=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbf P\left[n(\theta - X_n) \leq \theta x\right] \\
& = 1 - \exp(-x)
\end{align}
$$

Which is to say that this later sequence of variables converges in law to $E(0,1)$.